# Get which files have been modified files inside SCons builder action

Tags: python, scons

A Python function can be a SCons action used in a Builder, as described in the [SCons user manual](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#idm140113664650736). This function will be called by SCons whenever ANY of the sources changes. Sources are passed as a list of SCons Files objects
Inside this function I want to know if a specific source has been changed (and thus which source files forced SCons to rebuild the target of the builder).

so if 'file.target' is built using 'file1.src' and 'file2.src' using a custom builder that calls to python function 'custom_build':

```
env.CUSTOM_BUILDER('file.target', ['file1.src', 'file2.src'])

def custom_build(env, source, target):
    # Checks if file1.src has been modified
    if source[0].has_been_modified:  # Does something like this exist??
```

I have inspected this File objects while debugging, but without success. Is there any property to know that a specific file changed inside a SCons builder?

Comment: This is not the task of the Builder's Action. By defining the `*.src` files as sources to your target, SCons automatically registers the dependency between those files. When one of your source files change (depending on which Decider() method you use), your Action "custom_build" gets called. Its only task is to recreate the target from the given sources, the decision about when this step happens is at another level.

Comment: I understand your point. But supose that to recreate the target I need to know which files have been modified. Supose that the target is a simple file that lists files that have been modified from all possible sources that can be used to recreate the target. SCons has this information, so my question was on how to get it.

Comment: I have found and posted a solution that fits my needs. Thanks anyway for your time and concern in replying.

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution while searching on Node.__init__ package (SCons option --debug=explain provides here information about sources changed for each target). It is  not very nice, but seems to do the job. At least, it fits me well. The key is to use `changed_since_last_build` on the target.

```
def build(env, target, source):
    old = target[0].get_stored_info()
    old = old.binfo
    old.prepare_dependencies()
    old_bkids = old.bsources + old.bdepends + old.bimplicit
    old_bkidsigs = old.bsourcesigs + old.bdependsigs + old.bimplicitsigs
    osig = dict(zip(old_bkids, old_bkidsigs))

    for src_file, info in osig.iteritems():
        print str(src_file) + ' change status: ' + str(src_file.changed_since_last_build(target[0], info))
```

Comment: From what I can see, you're simply using the same method that SCons uses internally for finding out whether a file has changed or not. But you're executing this code right in the SConstruct/SConscript whenever you call your new "build" method explicitly. This will fail if (one of) your source(s) is generated during the build itself (e.g. autogenerated header). It may work for you in simple enough cases, but I'd like to warn other users to not use this method in their projects. They'll fall flat on their face with it, sorry.

Comment: Short additional remark: you're currently calling `changed_since_last_build` on the source, not on the target.